# Are there any blocks that don't damage your tools?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was farming with a friend of mine, and he was gathering crops with a diamond sword. I told him not to use a diamond sword as it takes damage, but then he told me crops don't damage your tools when broken.

What blocks don't damage your tools when you break them, besides crops?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but I find harvesting crop with seeds in my hand a good solution. Run a crop line harvesting, run it back sowing.

Comment: A good way to tell if a given activity uses up durability is to use wooden tools. They show durability use much more readily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Crops damage your tools, and in fact, sugarcane specifically will shred your tools faster than anything because of the extremely fast harvest rate. Any particular tool has X durability, (X being an arbitrary number) and every block destroyed by the tool reduces X by 1. When X < 0 the tool breaks.

However, this information does not always apply if you're playing on a modded server.

Comment: Not quite true. If a tool is used to break the appropriate type of block (pickaxe -> stone, shovel -> dirt), the durability will decrease by 1. If it is used to break any other type of block, the durability will decrease by 2.